# LWC call method with then which contains apex method

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, promises

Sorry if question label is frustrating. I am calling lwc method and do some actions on then and inside that lwc I there are apex method. But it gives me error on  then inside "firstMethod". I have tried async and it didn't help

Error: Cannot read properties of undefined

```
firstMethod() { 
    this.secondMethod(true, true).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    })
}

secondMethod(boolVar1,boolVar2) {
    if(boolVar2){
        apexMethod({boolVar:boolVar}).then((resp)=> {
            return resp;
            //Promise.resolve(resp) doesnt work too
        })
    } else {
       return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
}
```

I have added "return apexMethod" and it works

Comment: Hi. Please [edit] the question to add the specifics of the error (full error text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `secondMethod` returns a value if `boolVar2` is true and a Promise if not. The return type should always be the same.
Calling an apex method imperatively returns a Promise, that's why you handle it with `.then()`, so you can just return it, without handling:

```js
secondMethod(boolVar1, boolVar2) {
    if(boolVar2){
        return apexMethod({boolVar: boolVar});
    }
    return Promise.resolve(true);
}
```

I removed the `else` since it's unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, but  is it possible to just do 'return Promise.resolve(resp)' in second method? Doesnt work for me, but i need to do more logic here.

Comment: @fedove The answer is yes, but why would you need a one-line method that just `return Promise.resolve(true);`? It would return a promise, so whoever calls that method must handle it via `then()` or with `async/await`. Could you please add more details?